# Docker Desktop installation failed:Failed to start service

Tags: docker-desktop

Failed to start service: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

```
   at CommunityInstaller.Service.Service.<StartAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.Service.Manager.<AddServiceAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Could you please resolve this?

[image: Docker error]

[image: Hyper-v]

```html
Started on: 2021-06-05 19:17:13.110
File: C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Docker\install-log.txt
CommandLine: "C:\***\Docker Desktop Installer.exe" 
[19:17:13.119][ManifestAndExistingInstallationLoader] No install path specified, looking for default installation registry key
[19:17:13.122][Program] No installation found
[19:17:13.328][InstallWorkflow] Cancel pending background download
[19:17:13.352][InstallWorkflow] Using package: res:DockerDesktop
[19:17:13.355][InstallWorkflow] Downloading
[19:17:15.436][InstallWorkflow] Extracting manifest
[19:17:16.725][InstallWorkflow] Manifest found: version=64133, displayVersion=3.3.3, channelUrl=https://desktop.docker.com/win/stable/amd64/appcast.xml
[19:17:16.726][InstallWorkflow] Checking prerequisites
[19:17:17.599][InstallWorkflow] Prompting for optional features
[19:17:20.159][InstallWorkflow] Unpacking artifacts
[19:19:43.911][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.CreateGroupAction
[19:19:48.727][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.AddToGroupAction
[19:19:48.737][InstallWorkflow] Deploying component CommunityInstaller.ServiceAction
[19:19:48.740][InstallWorkflow-ServiceAction] Removing service
[19:19:48.744][InstallWorkflow-ServiceAction] Creating service
[19:19:51.300][InstallWorkflow] Installation failed
Exception type: System.Exception, Exception message: Component CommunityInstaller.ServiceAction failed: Failed to start service: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion, StackTrace:
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
[19:19:51.302][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.AddToGroupAction
[19:19:51.304][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.CreateGroupAction
[19:19:51.305][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.UnpackArtifactsStep
[19:19:51.312][FileSystem] Deleting C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker
[19:19:51.758][FileSystem] Deleted C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker successfully
[19:19:51.759][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.ExtractManifestStep
[19:19:51.760][InstallWorkflow] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.DownloadStep
```

Comment: Provider details about your hosting OS and machine details  and Hyper-V,/virtualization  configuration

Comment: Hi divyang4481,
  Thanks for your response,i updated my OS and machine details.
Regards,
Sowmya

Comment: you may have details  error log at  C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\service.txt, %LOCALAPPDATA%\Docker\install-log.txt, this may help to dig more details. so share that also

Comment: and what about  %LOCALAPPDATA%\Docker\install-log.txt,

Comment: Updated my install log in the snippet

Comment: Component CommunityInstaller.EnableFeaturesAction failed.
 How to enable?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the power service using the below steps,

1. Open msconfig.exe in the windows menu bar
2. Go to the "services" tab
3. Start typing "power" and it will auto find the correct service.
4. Untick the checkbox
5. Restart your PC
6. Make sure you do not have any Docker installation files in your
   drive
7. Start the installation process again and hopefully that'll work for
   you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error and for 5 days, I tried to fix it, tried nearly everything. Thankfully, thanks to someone's answer on Docker forums the issue is with Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) and to solve this you should run this cmd command in administrative mod:

```
CD C:\Windows\System32\WBEM && dir /b *.mof *.mfl | findstr /v /i uninstall > moflist.txt & for /F %s in (moflist.txt) do mofcomp %s
```

Solved my struggle with 4.23.0. Hope it solves for other people who experience the same problem.